# Image hover firefox with the nextgen gallery wordpress plugin

Tags: html, css, wordpress, firefox, nextgen-gallery

I am using wordpress with "nextgen gallery" plugin (i guess its css problem and not plugin issue off-course, just mentioned what i am using).

I edited some of the hover code, this is what I've reproduce :

```
.ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box .ngg-gallery-thumbnail a img {opacity: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        -webkit-transition: opacity .5s linear;
        -moz-transition:opacity .5s linear;
        width: 240px;
        height: 160px;
        display: block;

}

.ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box .ngg-gallery-thumbnail a img:hover {opacity: 0.8;
filter: alpha(opacity=80);
display: block;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s linear;
    content: "\f067"; 
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
    width: 240px;
    height: 160px;

    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 150px;
    background-color: rgba(255,247,102,0.4 )  !important;
    background: url('imgs/hover.png')  top left repeat-y !important ;


}
```

Url: [click here to see thumbnails on the website](http://hap.exactive.co.il/?page_id=22)

The problem: if you hover the thumbs with Chrome, you will see:
[image: Thumbnail hover image]

But on IE and firefox - its not working. The only thing that happend on hover in firefox is the opacity transition. Why?

Comment: maybe you could try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682424/my-css-image-hover-effect-does-not-work-in-firefox-or-opera

Comment: Not at all, thanks but not same issue

Comment: Could it be a z-index issue? Try using z-index: 9999 on hover div.

Comment: it can be firefox issue? i see even on envato premium themes like "enfold" that hover works on chrome, and not at firefox